# How to transfer dynamic link domain from one project to another

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have two firebase project. I have decided to delete older project, but want to keep the dynamic link domain to newer account. After deleting from older project, I get the following message while I try to insert the same domain at the newer project.

> Domain is being released. Please retry in one month

My query is to get a guideline to transfer dynamic link domain.

Edit: Domain are google provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to transfer it right away. You need to wait for a full month before you'll be able to use it to your new project. If somehow this looks urgent, you may file this to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/), but it's a case to case basis.

Comment: What about the same project? I was just trying to recreate the link after screwing up my rewrites in firebase.json. I want to recreate the dynamic link within the project.

Comment: @Ilia Sidorenko unfortunately, It's still the same. As I mentioned about, if it's urgent, reaching out to Firebase Support is the best way to resolve this.